# Django Pass id to URL after .exist query

Tags: django, view, foreign-keys

i have created a view set where it carry out a check if the User has created the object or not, in case the object is not created it will redirect him to a form to fill it and if is exist it will redirect him to the next step.

my current challenge is how to pass the id to the next view and set the foreign key based on it.

```
models.py:

class Startup ( models.Model ) :
    author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )

class Startup_About ( models.Model ) :
    str_about = models.ForeignKey ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    about = models.TextField ( 'About Startup' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    problem = models.TextField ( 'Problem/Opportunity' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )
    business_model = models.TextField ( 'Business Monitization Model' , max_length = 2000 , null = False ,blank = False )
    offer = models.TextField ( 'Offer to Investors' , max_length = 2000 , null = False , blank = False )

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.str_about)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@str_required
def create_startupform(request):
    q = Startup.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    if q.exists():
        return redirect ( 'appwizard')
    else:
        form = startupform ( request.POST or None )
        if form.is_valid ( ) :
            instance = form.save (commit = False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect ( 'appwizard', stup = instance.pk )
        else:
            form = startupform()
        return render ( request , 'str_name.html' , { 'form' : form } )

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
@method_decorator(str_required, name='dispatch')
class create_startupaboutform(CreateView):
    model= Startup_About
    template_name = 'create_about.html'
    form_class = startupaboutform
    success_url = '/str_detailedview/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.str_about = #i need to get the ID from the URL in both cases if the User had created the object or is going to create it#
        return super(create_startupaboutform,self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
 path ( 'appwizard/' , views.applicationwizard , name = 'appwizard' ) ,
 path('create_startupaboutform/', views.create_startupaboutform.as_view(), name='create_startupaboutform'),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. I am just listing 2 ways here.

1. Create a session variable that holds the id.
2. Modify URL to contain id `some-url/<int:pk>/` this `pk` will be ID.

Comment: i would prefer option 2, however, am not sure how to go about it since the first conition is a query to check but for the second is easy as i will add a variable that will hold the Instance.save data as PK but how to go about the first portion, then i have the second part which is the CBV to get the id and set the foreign key

Comment: one more thing i came to realize too is i need to pass the same value to all URLS